# Can I create a fungi dominant compost tea by brewing it in lower pH water?

Tags: compost, compost-tea

I have a lot of cheap compost available from my local landfill, but I would like to create a fungi dominated compost tea to apply to my perennials. Is it possible to create such a tea by using a lower pH water when brewing the tea? It's my understanding that fungi dominated soils are lower pH.